# Landscape/portrait orientation for my first app: why is it stuck?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've just deployed the ["first app" demo](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app) from Android Studio on a Nexus 10 emulator and on my physical Nexus 10 (API 22 / Lollipop 5.1).

On the emulator, when I change the orientation, the app rotates, but on my physical device it doesn't, it's stuck in landscape.

I've checked VLC rotates fine on my physical device for example, so the sensor is not the problem.

Comment: some apps rotate their views even if the device has locked orientation. Are you sure your device doesn't have the orientation locked?

Comment: "I've checked VLC rotates fine on my physical device for example, so the sensor is not the problem."

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you were talking about my app, but you were talking about VLC. So yes, you are right, VLC was just ignoring the lock  :)

Comment: sorry, I should have made it clear that I was referring to VLC. I hope that solves your problem now!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your screen orientation based on sensors use the below code

```
activityContext.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

Thats what VLC does rotates screen based on Sensors.

Comment: or ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR, which "Ignores user's setting to turn off sensor-based rotation" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#screenOrientation)

Comment: @Tristan please upvote and Accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: It's upvoted, but it's not the answer. The answer is : "VLC was just ignoring the lock", there was indeed a lock. If u understood my question and found it answerable, pls upvote it to remove the infamous "-1".